# .Net Core 3.1 Coravel scheduler and Directory.CreateDirectory

Tags: .net-core-3.1

I'm creating simple service with scheduler, that will execute some repetitive IO actions. I'm using Coravel scheduling library.

My configuration is pretty simple:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    host.Services.UseScheduler(scheduler => {
    scheduler.OnWorker("FirstTask");
    scheduler.Schedule<FirstService>().EveryMinute();

    scheduler.OnWorker("SecondTask");
    scheduler.Schedule<SecondService>().EveryFifteenSeconds();
  });
    host.Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
          services.AddScheduler();
          services.AddTransient<FirstService>();
          services.AddTransient<SecondService>();
          services.AddOptions();
          services.Configure<DbOptions>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("DbOptions"));
        })
      .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));
```

Simple service

```
public class FirstService : IInvocable
{
  private readonly ILogger<FirstService> _logger;
  private readonly DbService _context;

  public FirstService(ILogger<FirstService> logger, DbContext context)
  {
    _logger = logger;
    _context = context;
  }

  public async Task Invoke()
  {
    _logger.LogInformation("FirstService was invoked!");
    var data = _context.Collect();
    await StoreData(data);
  }

  public async Task StoreData(string url)
  {
    try
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_config.PhotoWebPrefix) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_config.PhotoRootPath)) throw new ArgumentException("Wrong configuration");
      using var client = new WebClient();
      var path = url.Replace(_config.PhotoLinkPrefix, _config.PhotoRootPath).Replace("/", "\\");
      var result = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
      Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
      await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      _logger.LogError(e, "Error in StoreData");
      throw;
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I'm trying to create a directory like this (example just for simplicity). Data are fine, I've tried them in console app and everything worked well.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"‪C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\testDir\Photo\2019\12\11\528\");
```

I receiving an error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\Projects\PROJ_NAME\Service\‪C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\testDir\Photo\2019\12\11\528\

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't contain any call to `Directory.CreateDirectory`. The string you posted contains a leading invisible character. Where do you make that call and where does the path come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question's code doesn't contain any call to `Directory.CreateDirectory`. The string itself starts with the invisible [Left-To-Right Embedding character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm), so it can't be treated as an absolute path.

This expression :

```
(int)@"‪C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\testDir\Photo\2019\12\11\528\"[0]
```

Returns `8234`

Wherever that string comes from, it needs to be cleaned up. Was it copied from some document perhaps?

Comment: You are right, my problem was configuration, more specifically this `_config.PhotoRootPath` contained an invisible character, that made my day hell. Thank you!